# CodeMagic without Mac Automatic code signing Error

Tags: codemagic

I followed the instructions on the documentation (which is great by the way):

https://docs.codemagic.io/code-signing/ios-code-signing/

But I am still getting some errors:

```
Did not find matching provisioning profiles for code signing!
```

and

```
error: Signing for "Runner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This end up being an error in my Code base, not in the process.

I was able to solve it by accessing my "ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj" file and changing all the references in PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER.

From (default setting when first created the App)

```
com.example.yourApp
```

To (the reference you're using in CodeMagic)

```
com.yourapp.app
```